# Last-child doesn't seem to be working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This is the code I have:

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#nav ul li a {
 width:162px;
 background:url('http://i.imgur.com/DmeCv.png') -164px 0px;

#nav ul li:first-child a {
 width:164px;
 background:url('http://i.imgur.com/DmeCv.png');
}

#nav ul li:last-child a {
 background:url('http://i.imgur.com/DmeCv.png') -326px 0px;
}
```

So far, so good. This works, and displays the image properly.

```css
#nav ul li a:hover {
 background:url('http://i.imgur.com/DmeCv.png') -164px -50px;
}

#nav ul li:first-child a:hover {
 background:url('http://i.imgur.com/DmeCv.png') 0px -50px;

#nav ul li:last-child a:hover {
 background:url('http://i.imgur.com/DmeCv.png') -326px -50px;
}
```

This doesn't work, however. It displays the mid section hover image, rather than the last-child hover image.

Here is an example:

http://result.dabblet.com/gist/2973127/8bf204a16e7caca43ad129cad141fa4810bf18ce

Comment: what is it supposed to do? what doesn't work? it looks fine to me..

Comment: In which browser did you try it? `:last-child` only works in the recent browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child

Comment: @deathApril, the last item has square corners when hovering over it. Aside: I'm sooo thankful I'm able to design for newer browsers and use `border-radius` and `linear-gradient` instead of images...

Comment: Ewww, redeclared shorthand styles with the same background image URL repeated *six times*.

Comment: Andrew, this is a prime example of why proper indentation and spacing is more than just personal preference. After fixing up your code, the issue can be spotted rather easily (see [hawaii.five-0's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11158515/526741)).

Answer (score 10):

In your CSS example, you are missing your closing curly brace `}` in `first-child a:hover`.

Comment: So that's a curly bracket, this `)` is a parenthesis.

Comment: So CSS isn't a piece of code, it's a proper noun; those backticks shouldn't be around it.